# SQL query results combined with unique values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  star_user.name_user, star_group.name_group,   star_addresses.email 
FROM star_addresses

JOIN star_user_group
ON star_user_group.id_user_groupu = star_addresses.user_id

JOIN star_group
ON star_group.id_group = star_user_group.id_group_groupu

JOIN star_user
ON star_user.corespondence_user = star_addresses.id_address

JOIN star_news_group
ON star_news_group.groupid_newsg = star_user_group.id_group_groupu

WHERE newsid_newsg = 5;
```

after i run the above query I get the following output:

```
name_user|name_group|email
Zuma     |A         |abc@zz.com
Rafe     |B         |xyz@nn.com
Adam     |D         |aaa@bb.com
Zuma     |B         |abc@zz.com
Zuma     |C         |abc@zz.com
```

What I would like to have instead of repetitive values of Zuma like her name_user and email is this:

```
name_user|name_group|email
Zuma     |A,B,C     |abc@zz.com
```

So, how to get that? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: I am using MYSQL, and I am using PHP too. The SQL query what I wrote above is written in PHP. It is running fine, but I get Zuma 3 times in 3 rows. I want to have Zuma and her groups names  seperated by comma with  her email id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT  star_user.name_user, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT star_group.name_group) name_group,   
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT star_addresses.email) email
FROM    star_addresses
        JOIN star_user_group
            ON star_user_group.id_user_groupu = star_addresses.user_id
        JOIN star_group
            ON star_group.id_group = star_user_group.id_group_groupu
        JOIN star_user
            ON star_user.corespondence_user = star_addresses.id_address
        JOIN star_news_group
            ON star_news_group.groupid_newsg = star_user_group.id_group_groupu
WHERE   newsid_newsg = 5;
GROUP   BY star_user.name_user
```